# creating a customized stat file out of files a current directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing, csv

I have files like these:

```
$ cat A9E27.txt
person,42%
person,60%
$ cat ffn2eG6.txt
train,85%
$ cat sBHFgkv.txt  
person,85%
person,73%
chair,44%
person,57%
$ cat A8eVAmK.txt
```

etc etc
Some of my txt files are actually even empty.
how can I create a file that is like this

```
1,A9E27.txt,person,42%,person,60%
2,ffn2eG6.txt,train,85%
3,sBHFgkv.txt,person,85%,person,73%,chair,44%,person,57%
4,A8eVAmK.txt
5, etc etc
```

where 1 shows the file number when I sort my file names alphabetically something like ls -1 | sort
and A9E27.txt is the file name, and each line of file contents comes in front of it separated by comma

UPDATE:
SchrodingersScat's answer from Ubuntu IRC is almost correct on stdout:

```
$ for i in * ; do echo -n "$i"; cat "$i" | sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n/, /;ba;}' ; done
5Co16.txtA9E27.txtperson,42%, person,60%
ffn2eG6.txttrain,85%
Kkc4e.txtsBHFgkv.txtperson,85%, person,73%, chair,44%, person,57%
```

gives correct answer but how can I save this result shown on stdout into a file correctly?

Comment: `for ...; done > output.txt`

Comment: that produced results that did not make sense

Comment: Your own answer does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`kerframil` from `bash` IRC:

```
$  i=1; for f in *; do [[ -f $f ]] || continue; data=$(tr '\n' ',' < "$f"); printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "$((i++))" "$f" "${data%,}"; done > ../../in-your-file-correctly.txt
```

notes:

```
/join #bash
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `perl` in slurp mode?

```
$ perl -F'\n' -0777ne 'print join(",", ++$n, $ARGV, @F), "\n"' *.txt
1,A8eVAmK.txt
2,A9E27.txt,person,42%,person,60%
3,ffn2eG6.txt,train,85%
4,sBHFgkv.txt,person,85%,person,73%,chair,44%,person,57%
```

Note that the shell `*.txt` glob causes the files to be processed in the default collation order of your locale - that might not be what you consider to be "alphabetic" (although it should be the same as that produced by `ls -1`, I think).

To save the result to a file, redirect it:

```
perl -F'\n' -0777ne 'print join(",", ++$n, $ARGV, @F), "\n"' *.txt > somefile
```